# How to get back lower case column names in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working with a database which has all uppercase snakecase column names and when I fetch them with eloquent I do something like:

```
    foreach($data as $key => $item){
        $data[$key] = array_change_key_case($item);
    }
```

This makes the keys ie the column names to lower case, but it soon becomes inefficient since I need to nested arrays too like so:

```
    foreach($tasks as $key => $task){
        foreach($task['users'] as $innerKey => $user){
            $task['users'][$innerKey] = array_change_key_case($user);
        }
        $tasks[$key] = array_change_key_case($task);
    }
```

And I can't change the database. Is there a way I can make eloquent give me back the column names in lower case?

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence package.

then you can map the names according to you need,

// Mappable User model
`protected $maps = [
    'user_name' => 'USER_NAME',
];`

//getting mapped attirbutes
$user->user_name; // returns $user->USER_NAME

Comment: This seems promising. Thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @shoieb0101 Short answers are still answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can transform column names at the driver level [using PDO attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php). To do so, set your [Laravel connection options](http://fideloper.com/laravel-pdo-connection-options) (in `app/config/database.php`) like so:

```
return array(
    'connections' => array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'options'   => array(
                PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
            ),
        ),
     )
)
```

The [default](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#L21) is `PDO::CASE_NATURAL`, which is why your code sees them as the database has them stored.

---

**Update:** If you are using MySQL, you might consider setting  [lower_case_table_names = 2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names), which tells the server:

> If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases.

Comment: Relations have stopped working now. Any idea on that? :)

Comment: `return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'RBAC_USERS_ROLES', 'USR_UID', 'ROL_UID');` This is what you mean right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Those need to be lower-cased, as Eloquent uses those literally in SQL statements.

Comment: this option work fine in sqlserver for anyone have problems with fields names

Answer (score 0):

If override the `getAttribute()` method on your model you can transform the key before the call:

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $databaseColumn = implode('_', array_map('ucfirst', explode('_', $key)));

    return parent::getAttribute($databaseColumn);
}
```

This will allow you to do `$model->get_model_param` and it will access `$model->Get_Model_Param` on the model.